# Proper Format for Byobu's windows.tmux?

Tags: tmux, byobu

In Byobu 5.17 (using tmux 1.6), how ought I format the windows.tmux file? I've poked around a bit, but have been unable to find a proper answer.

For reference, here's the screen version of what I want:

```
screen -t log watch -n 10 tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog /var/log/auth.log /var/log/ dmesg
screen -t mem watch -n 30 "df -h; echo ""; free -mt"
screen -t top top
screen -t bash /bin/bash
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Is this really still not answerable? I haven't seen any windows.tmux instructions out there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, but you might also want to look into [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) or [tmuxp](https://github.com/tony/tmuxp) to specify tmux profiles in YAML.

```
new -s tmuxs # creates a new tmux session, replace "tmuxy" with whatever you'd like to name the session
new-window -n log 'watch -n 10 tail -n 5 /var/log/syslog /var/log/auth.log /var/log/dmesg'
new-window -n mem 'watch -n 30 "df -h; echo ""; free -mt"'
new-window -n top 'top'
new-window -n bash
```

It's pretty self explanatory, create a session and then start creating windows, naming them via `'-n'` and including the command you want to run as the last argument.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out how to get it to work. First you need an update to version Byobu 5.85 or later. Here is the [corresponding commit with the fix](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/commit/af180e08e204b7c965cacc4d8f766ac02b3e5a97) and there is a [PPA for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~byobu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

<s>First, check that the line `source-file $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/windows.tmux` in `/usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc` is uncommented or it won't work.</s>

As you can see in updated documentation part of the commit you need to chain your commands with semicolons. To take the [tmux example from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Session_initialization) and make it work it would look like this:

```
new -A -s SessionName -n WindowName nano;
neww -n foo/bar top;
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 top;
selectw -t 1;
selectp -t 0
```

Don't forget to add `-A` to the new/new-session command or Byobu will be unable to reconnect to an existing session.

You should update to a newer version of tmux if you are on 14.04 or an older version than tmux 1.9, to avoid running into this issue: [Create new-window with current directory in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12032/49853)

Comment: This question probably still gets a lot of hits, so let me amend this:

If you have issues with split panes duplicating, and you are running Ubuntu 16.04, or just newer versions of Byobu *DO NOT UNCOMMENT THE LINE IN `/usr/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc`*.